# How to use Vaadin add-on with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, gwt, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin4spring

I'm using Vaadin 7.6.3 with Spring Boot. I'm trying to use the [PopupButton](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/popupbutton) add-on (but I don't think the issue is specific to the add-on).

I added the add-on as a dependency to gradle. This is the code for creating a PopupButton:

```
PopupButton btn = new PopupButton("Test Button");
btn.setContent(new Label("Test"));
layout.addComponent(btn);
```

Via the Vaadin plugin for Gradle I ran the task `vaadinCompile` which created the file `src/main/resources/addon/client/ListaideWidgetset.gwt.xml` and serveral files in `src/main/webapp/VAADIN/gwt-unitCache` and 
`src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets/addon.client.ListaideWidgetset`. I also added `@Widgetset("addon.client.ListaideWidgetset")` to my UI. I confirmed that the widgetset is used via the client's `?debug` mode.

Content of `ListaideWidgetset.gwt.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Vaadin//DTD Vaadin 7//EN" "https://raw.github.com/vaadin/gwt/master/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<!-- WS Compiler: manually edited -->
<module>
        <inherits name="com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet" />
        <set-configuration-property name="devModeRedirectEnabled" value="true" />
        <set-property name="user.agent" value="ie8,ie9,gecko1_8,safari,ie10" />
        <source path="client" />
        <source path="shared" />
        <collapse-all-properties />
        <set-property name="compiler.useSymbolMaps" value="true" />
</module>
```

The problem is that on the client the button shows up as a standard button (no chevron) and doesn't open a popup when clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your widgetset does not contain the addon.  See the the [example](https://github.com/henrikerola/PopupButton/blob/master/demo/src/main/resources/org/vaadin/hene/popupbutton/widgetset/PopupbuttonDemoWidgetset.gwt.xml#L28):

```
 <inherits name="org.vaadin.hene.popupbutton.widgetset.PopupbuttonWidgetset" />
```

Once added, recompile the widgetset, restart your application.

Usually the gradle plugin can handle this for you, but that feature can be disabled and or some other configuration error could prevent it.  Hard to tell without the `build.gradle`...

#### edit

The gradle vaadin plugin seems not to be able to handle this addon properly.  As a workaround disable the automatic management for widgetset, which prevents regeneration of the `gwt.xml`.  See `manageWidgetset` in https://github.com/johndevs/gradle-vaadin-plugin/wiki/Tasks-and-configuration-DSL).  E.g. add `vaadinCompile.manageWidgetset = false` in your `vaadin{}`-block.

Comment: When I add that line to the widgetset and run `vaadinCompile` the widgetset gets overriden and reset to the original one O.o This is my [gradle.build](http://pastebin.com/UmrktUmB).

Comment: @zero_cool first of all, the current version of the vaadin gradle plugin is 0.11.1.  if the plugin does not properly handle the plugins, you might have to disable widgetset management (see `manageWidgetset` in https://github.com/johndevs/gradle-vaadin-plugin/wiki/Tasks-and-configuration-DSL)

Comment: I updated to 0.11.1 which didn't do anything. I added `vaadinCompile.manageWidgetset = false` to build.gradle. Now the widgetset doesn't get overridden anymore. The add-on is also working now. Thanks a million :)